# Amcharts doesnt show one balloon for all graphs

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to have 1 balloon for all stacked graps. I changed my code to be using [this](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/showing-only-one-balloon-for-all-graphs/). Unfortunelly `messages` data is not displayed.

[image]

Did I do something wrong?

```
function createChart(chartDiv, title) {
    return AmCharts.makeChart(chartDiv, {
        "type": "stock",    
        "theme": "black",           
        "chartCursor": {
            "oneBalloonOnly": true,
        },
        "dataSets": [{
            "fieldMappings": [{
                "fromField": "ack",
                "toField": "ack"
            }, {
                "fromField": "messages",
                "toField": "messages"
            }],
            "color": "#1d6a96",
            "categoryField": "date",
        }],
        "categoryAxesSettings": {
            "alwaysGroup": true,
            "groupToPeriods": ["6mm"],
            "minPeriod": "4mm",
            "dashLength": 0,
        },
        "panels": [{
            "gridAboveGraphs": true,
            "stockGraphs": [{
                "type": "column",
                "id": "g1",
                "valueField": "ack",
                "lineColor": "#7f8da9",
                "fillColors": "#7f8da9",
                "fillAlphas": 0.85,
                "periodValue": "Sum",
                "useDataSetColors": false,
                "balloonText": "Ack:[[value]], missing:[[messages]]",
            }, {
                "type": "column",
                "id": "g2",
                "valueField": "messages",
                "lineColor": "#FDD400",
                "fillColors": "#FDD400",
                "fillAlphas": 0.85,
                "periodValue": "Close",
                "useDataSetColors": false,
                "showBalloon": false
            }],
        }],
        "valueAxesSettings": {
            "inside": false,
            "id": "v1",
            "dashLength": 0,
            "minimum": 0,
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "stackType": "regular",
            "axisAlpha": 0.5,
            "showFirstLabel": false,
        },
    });
}
```

I am paasing data to chart from ajax response as json.

```
function insertChartData(chart, response) {
    var dataProvider = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < response.Stats.length; i++) {
        dataProvider.push({
            date: new Date(response.Stats[i].Checked),
            ack: response.Stats[i].Income,
            messages: response.Stats[i].Messages,
        });
    }

    chart.AmChart.dataSets[0].dataProvider = dataProvider;
    chart.AmChart.validateData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the stock chart's [data grouping functionality](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/understanding-data-grouping-of-stock-chart/). When it aggregates your data, referencing fields by name won't work anymore as they aren't preserved in the internal data grouping structure (this is also the case with fields like `lineColorField` as well). You'll need to disable data grouping by setting `maxSeries` to 0 in order to reference properties by name.

```
    "categoryAxesSettings": {
        "maxSeries": 0,
        "minPeriod": "4mm",
        "dashLength": 0,
    },
```

This will impact performance if you have a large amount of data.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/353ebe6158e577f99634d7fbc3c06705?editors=0010)

Comment: `maxSeries` doesn't solve the problem. Setting `alwaysGroup` to `false` solves it. Unfortunelly after that I am getting strange results like this: https://puu.sh/BP8x9/f96b9cefa6.jpg

Comment: [Yes it does](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/353ebe6158e577f99634d7fbc3c06705?editors=0010). Note that I explicitly removed alwaysGroup and groupToPeriods as they are not needed with `maxSeries: 0`. Compare the balloon after commenting out maxSeries: 0. I'm not sure what I'm looking at in your screenshot as I'm not seeing a problem on my end in my codepen. A fiddle with your data would help.